# onsen notification undefined ios

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, onsen-ui

I am displaying a ons.notification like:

```
ons.notification.alert({
                        message: 'test',
                        buttonLabel: 'OK'
});
```

This method works in the browser, but fails in iOS.

Error:

```
 ERROR: Error: dialogElement.show is not a function. (In 'dialogElement.show', 'dialogElement.show' is undefined)
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed with updated onsen. Migrated from 1.3.5 to 1.3.15.... might help to stay updated i guess

Comment: Onsen is now on 2.0.10.  Version 2.x is awesome!